# Variation of the geometry of a Dirichlet region as the defining point varies

Tags: gr.group-theory, hyperbolic-geometry, fuchsian-groups

Let $\Gamma$ a Fuchsian group acting on the hyperbolic plane $\mathfrak{H}$.  For me, I am most interested in the case where $\Gamma$ has a fundamental domain that is a finite-polygon with all endpoints in the hyperbolic plane, but I'm also happy to hear about the more general setting.

Let $Fix(\Gamma)$ denote the set of points in the hyperbolic plane $\mathfrak{H}$ that are fixed by some nontrivial element of $\Gamma$.  Given a point $P \notin Fix(\Gamma)$, then we have the Dirichlet region
$$
\Delta(p) = \{ Q \in \mathfrak{H} : d(Q,P) \leq d( gQ,P) \text{ for all } g \in \Gamma \}
$$
which is a fundamental domain of $\Gamma$ (meaning the $\Gamma$-translates of $\Delta(P)$ cover all of $\mathfrak{H}$ and the different translates have disjoint interiors).  $\Delta(p)$ is always a closed convex polygon (possibly with infinitely many sides and possibly with vertices and/or sides at infinity).

I am familiar with static pictures of this setup and I am wondering what happens as $P$ is varied throughout $\mathfrak{H} - Fix(\Gamma)$ - hence the question, how does the geometry of $\Delta(P)$ change as $P$ varies?

By geometry, I mean the number of sides, the area, the lengths of the sides, number of points/sides at infinity etc.  Are there animations of this anywhere?

Some simple specific cases I have in mind are hyperbolic triangle groups $\Delta(a,b,c)$, surface groups, and the modular group, but I am happy to hear about other examples.